# package a software for Windows with wine

Tags: python, cx-freeze, esky

I use Esky/cx_freeze to package a python program for different OS. When I have to do it for windows, I use Windows 7 on VirtualBox.

However, I find this method pretty unpleasant and heavy. So I wonder, is there a way to package programs for Windows through Wine ?

I would basically need to install all the libraries I need, then run some commands like "python setup.py bdist_esky".

I know the cx_freeze doc doesn't advice this, but I'm trying to find a better way to package my software. I wonder if someone has a better option.

Comment: Might be overkill for small projects but you could set up a build server that handles downloading your code to VMs of all platforms you're interested in and doing the build. I don't really see any reliable ways of producing binaries for Windows that doesn't involve a Windows machine.

Comment: One of my current project is not small, that's interesting. Could it also be done for Mac OS ? Do you have any link to start ?

Comment: Pyinstaller seems to be working with wine: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pyinstaller/veq3BlA_Bns/YlmKUofUfbgJ

Comment: No, PyInstaller is not a solution. It doesn't handle python 3. And I don't think it's compatible with Esky.

Comment: @Rififi Well there's a few options, but before you start down this route: are you really interested in producing binaries or do you just want a way to package your applications in a cross platform way (while still having the deployment contain the source)?

Comment: I don't want the deployment to contain the sources, but I'm open to any cross-platform solution otherwise.

Comment: [Pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can build Windows installers from Linux/Mac, without involving Wine at all. But it doesn't support hiding the source code, and it targets Windows only.

Comment: Good suggestion @Thomas K. I think it can be a good alternative for small projects, maybe the ones which don't require deployment on Mac OS. But it might fall short for important projects.

Comment: My feeling is kind of the other way round: I've found that freezing tools are increasingly brittle with larger projects, and I've built Pynsist to be more reliable and easier to understand, so I think it could be more suitable for larger projects (though it's still quite young, so caveat emptor). I think Windows/Linux/Mac are different enough that it's better to use separate tools to package for each system, rather than one tool that tries to deal with everything.